# How do I check the url for socket error ruby

Tags: ruby, url, controller, uri, response

```
 uri = URI("http://#{url}")
 res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri) ### Code here
```

I read the path URLs from the txt file.
When a url socket error or timeout error is given the program closes.
To prevent it, I want to check that it does not give a url socket error.

```
uri = URI("http://#{url}")
if (uri== worked ) ### What should I use here?
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an `if` statement, you should use an exception handler for this.  Assuming the errors you're expecting are `SocketError` and `Errno::ETIMEDOUT`, that would look something like this:

```
begin
  # code that might raise the error
rescue SocketError => e
  # run this code in the event of a socket error
rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
  # run this code in the event of a timeout
ensure
  # run this code unless an error is raised that isn't accounted for
end
```